# Accessing Files created by Webapp hosted by Azure

Tags: azure, flask, azure-blob-storage, web-hosting

New to cloud hosting in Azure, recently created a flask webapp that will open, if not generate a txt file(with root directory), but i dont think if there is any way to access that file? i have not created or subscribed to any storage services provided by azure yet. Will i be charged since the file is technically stored somewhere but i cant access it?

Comment: you can use `https://<websitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui` to check the root directory of the websites, all the files will be available related to your web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a flask app which creates a `text.txt` file and deployed it to web app in Azure using VS code.

you can get the created file inside the file **`output.tar.gz`**.

**`app.py`:**

```py
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def Hello():
    text ='hello, File created using flask app'
    with open('text.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)
    return "this is a Flask app"


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

**`deployment`:**
[image]

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

- Open kudu for linux app using this url `https://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`.
- Go to `File Manager`, go to directory `site/wwwroot` and download the `output.tar.gz` file.
- `text.txt` file will be available inside the file. as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]